# CSS: Revert to inline styling on hover

Tags: css, inline-styles

I have text wrapped in SPANs that are generated by Javascript, and when generated it includes inline styling. So something like:

```
<div id="test">
    <span style="color: red">Text 1</span>
    <span style="color: blue">Text 2</span>
    <span style="color: green">Text 3</span>
    ...
</div>
```

However, normally I want all the text to be one color, and only on hover should the special coloring defined inline be visible. The problem of course is that in order to override the inline styling for the non-hover styling, I have to include the `!important` declaration. Then when I define the `:hover` styling, there's nothing I can do.

```
#test > span {
    color: black !important;
}
#test:hover > span {
    color: inline; // Does not exist!
}
```

Is there any option I'm unaware of? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

I *can't* run the Javascript onmouseover to add the inline styling, then remove onmouseout. Just in case someone wanted to suggest it.

**EDIT:**

I did just think of a crazy solution: Embed all the text SPANs in parent SPANs, give the parents the inline styling, force the children to be a uniform color through the important flag, and then on hover force the children to `inherit` from the parents....... That would work, right? Anything more elegant?

Comment: I think there is nothing like color:inline. and you change color on hover by using !important because you are using it before. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2KFr4/)

Comment: Why don't you give each span a `class` or use CSS3's `:nth-child()` selector and then style the `:hover` color for each of them? Then you would still be able to color the spans black ahead of time without using `!important`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting the text in another span should work and you can inherit the color from the parent.

Personally I think you should give them each a class and change their color on hover.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/576Ez/

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
    <span class="red hover">Text 1</span>
    <span class="blue hover">Text 2</span>
    <span class="green hover">Text 3</span>
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test .red.hover:hover {
    color: red;
}
#test .blue.hover:hover {
    color: blue;
}
#test .green.hover:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! As I suspected, there was a very obvious solution. My brain was just too tired, I think. There really was no need for the double class. I just have a `#test > span {color: black;}` then a `#test:hover > span.red {color: red;}`. As an additional complication, I have another place where the SPANs _are_ supposed to display their color all the time, so I had to add a second set of selectors into the hover rule. But otherwise, perfect. Thanks!